# With the PHP Riak Client, how would I search two indexes for values simultaneously?

Tags: php, riak

I have a dataset in [Riak](http://basho.com/riak/) with different items indexed (using `index_bin`). How would I go about searching objects where two of these indexes have particular values in a single request? Example: gender, last_name with gender = male, and last_name = Smith

Would I use Map/Reduce? If so, any example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limitation of secondary indexes in Riak is that only a single index can be searched at a time. You will therefore not be able to directly combine indexes.

As the index data is stored in the metadata of the record, you could create a mapreduce job that takes one 2i query as input and has a map phase that filters on the other based on the metadata. Using mapreduce this way may however be quite slow and inefficient as all data passed into the map phase function need to be read from disk.

If you are looking to serve a reasonably common and predictable request, you can always create and use a composite index instead. You could e.g. create an index named `gender_name_bin` which could have values like `male_Smith`. This will allow you to do a range query on the last part of the index as long as the first part is fixed, which gives some flexibility.

It is in recent versions also possible to filter secondary index values based on regular expressions, which does not require the actual object to be loaded. More information about this can be found [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/2i/#Querying).

Comment: Thanks Christian - that confirms what I thought. I hope that in future Riak versions it will be possible to query multiple indexes. I guess the other alternative would be to use SOLR and full text searching, which should be faster than running Map/Reduce jobs.

Comment: I expect the new version of Riak Search in Riak 2.0, which integrates Riak with Solr, to replace a lot of secondary index use where flexibility and the ability to query multiple fields is required.